# How do I locate docker image in a registry when only knowing image name and registry url by running podman and skopeo tool?

Tags: search, containers, registry, openshift, podman

If I only know docker image name and registry url, and I am running podman and skopeo and etc. tools, how do I locate docker image in a registry?

I need to find out its full path in the registry and tag.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

can you explain more details.

From what I understand you maybe want to list the available images, e.g. using skopeo can be achieved as:

> skopeo list-tags docker://docker.io/fedora

If this is not what you are looking for, then please share more information. What registries are involved, do you want to list the running images using podman cli and from that detect the full remote registry path and the tag used when pulling the image?

Comment: Thank you @MrSimpleMind.

For example, if my target image and tag were docker://docker.io/myname/fedora:1.0 (but I don't know the full path yet, it's what I try to identify). At this point, I only know "docker.io" is the registry and "fedora" is the image. How can I find the full path "docker.io/myname/fedora:1.0"?

Thank you